# How to use an npm package (chart.js) once installed?

Tags: laravel, npm, chart.js

I'm making a practice Laravel site, and I've installed chart.js via npm install.

This is a dumb questions but now how do I use it (or anything installed via npm) from here?

The files are installed in the node modules folder. Am I supposed to reference them files using  tags in my page headers?

If I do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Then it works,  I can get a chart to appear. But this doesn't feel right. Isn't npm supposed to take care of all that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in your code snippet is importing the package for global use. NPM is more of a package manager (Node Package Manager) that installs packages and manages dependencies.

So to answer your question, no NPM doesn't usually handle that automatically. What you're doing is one way of accessing/importing the package once its installed. Another way would be https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm-packages-in-your-projects .

Answer (score 0):

Laravel makes use of webpack aka [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#copying-files-and-directories) where you can copy files as well. For example jQuery:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'public/js/jquery.min.js');
```

Then on the page where you need to js/css you can make use of [stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks) where you can

```
@push('js')
    <script src="/js/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
@endpush
```

to include your script. Just run `npm run dev` on development and `npm run prod` if you are ready to upload. If you use version control, don't forget to add files copied by Laravel Mix in your public css and js folders.

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js does not seem to be friendly for npm users, in version 3 you need to register chart elements, because of tree shaking. This is an example with **chart.js@3.6.1**

**HTML**

```
<div style="width: 600px;">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
import { Chart, LinearScale, BarElement, BarController, CategoryScale } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(LinearScale, BarElement, BarController, CategoryScale);
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The result
[image]

Comment: Actually this change makes chart.js very friendly for npm users since with treeshaking you can only use what you need. This will make your bundle smaller which means your users have to download less making your site load faster. Also you can still use the old import and let chart.js handle everything by importing from: 'chart.js/auto'