# How to use chart js npm module to generate chart through node using html/ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I want to use chart js node modules instead of cdn to generate chart, and also create chart through node like in app.js file and then send to html/ejs file, but I can't figure out how to, and all the articles/tutorials on internet are using CDN.

Also, I have went through these questions :
[How to use Chart JS by Node JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62232243/how-to-use-chart-js-by-node-js)

[How to use an npm package (chart.js) once installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56993885/how-to-use-an-npm-package-chart-js-once-installed)

But they are not helping.

app.js code :

```
const express=require( 'express' );
const Chart=require( 'chart.js' );
const path=require( 'path' );
const { sortBy }=require( 'async' );

const app=express();

const viewsPath=path.join( __dirname, './views/pages' );
app.set( "view engine", "ejs" );
app.set( 'views', viewsPath );
app.use( "/public", express.static( "public" ) );

app.listen( 4000, () => {
    console.log( 'listening at port 4000' );
} );

var ctx=document.getElementById( 'myChart' ); // But this says document is not defined, as it's in ejs file, and if I remove it then ctx is not defined.
var myChart=new Chart( ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [ 'Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange' ],
        datasets: [ {
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [ 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3 ],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        } ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
} );

app.get( '/', function ( req, res ) {
    res.render( 'one' );
} );
```

one.ejs

```
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

But I can't figure out how to create and export chart and then render to one.ejs.

PS: I want to understand and do this on node as much as possible, as I then plan to use it in puppeteer.

Also, I can do this through cdn as here : https://jsfiddle.net/abhishek_soni/38mfez7g/1/

Every advice and help is highly appreciated.